# Route:put not working in my laravel/react/sanctum project?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, xampp

I have a react component that display the company when the company first login : the the form is filled by this info coming  from my localstorage. Now the issue I have is when I try to change something in the form and click save all I expect that the backend (controller) update the authenticated company info in my database table (companies) : but when I have this problem:

When I use this code down here for my update function I get connected to the database:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        
        return response()->json(['Message' => 'Connected to DB ', 'company detected'], 201);

    }
```

but if I add my logic I get an error saying:

> "Profile.jsx:43 PUT" <http://localhost:8000/api/Company/update>" net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth::guard('company')->user(); // Get the authenticated user (company)
        $company = $user->company;

        // Validate the incoming data
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'company_name' => 'required|string',
            'industry' => 'required|string',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'company_contact' => 'required|string',
            'headquarters' => 'required|string',
            'ceo_founder' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        $company->update([
            'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
            'industry' => $request->input('industry'),
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
            'company_contact' => $request->input('company_contact'),
            'headquarters' => $request->input('headquarters'),
            'ceo_founder' => $request->input('ceo_founder'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')), // Hash the password
        ]);


        $company->save();


        return response()->json(['message' => 'Company info updated successfully', 'company' => $company]);
        // return response()->json(['Message' => 'Connected to DB ', 'company detected'], 201);

    }
```

Here is my controller full code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class CompanyAuthController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('company');
    }

    // Register method for API
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // ... Registration logic as previously mentioned
        // return response()->json(['Message' => 'Connected to DB '], 201);

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'company_name' => 'required|string',
            'industry' => 'required|string',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'company_contact' => 'required|string',
            'headquarters' => 'required|string',
            'ceo_founder' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:companies',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        $company = new Company();
        $company->company_name = $request->input('company_name');
        $company->industry = $request->input('industry');
        $company->description = $request->input('description');
        $company->company_contact = $request->input('company_contact');
        $company->headquarters = $request->input('headquarters');
        $company->ceo_founder = $request->input('ceo_founder');
        $company->email = $request->input('email');
        $company->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        // $company->save();

        try {
            $company->save();
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Company account created successfully!'], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create Company account'], 500);
        }
    }

    // Login method for API
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // ... Login logic as previously mentioned
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $company = Company::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (!$company || !Hash::check($request->password, $company->password)) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }

        if ($company->company_name !== $request->company_name) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'company_name' => ['The provided company name is incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }

        $token = $company->createToken('company-token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Company logged in successfully',
            'token' => $token,
            'company' => $company,
        ], 200);
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth::guard('company')->user(); // Get the authenticated user (company)
        $company = $user->company;

        // Validate the incoming data
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'company_name' => 'required|string',
            'industry' => 'required|string',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'company_contact' => 'required|string',
            'headquarters' => 'required|string',
            'ceo_founder' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        $company->update([
            'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
            'industry' => $request->input('industry'),
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
            'company_contact' => $request->input('company_contact'),
            'headquarters' => $request->input('headquarters'),
    
        'ceo_founder' => $request->input('ceo_founder'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')), // Hash the password
        ]);


        $company->save();


        return response()->json(['message' => 'Company info updated successfully', 'company' => $company]);
        // return response()->json(['Message' => 'Connected to DB ', 'company detected'], 201);

    }

    // Logout method for API
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        // ... Logout logic as previously mentioned
    }
}
```

Here is my api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyAuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeAuthContoller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

// Authenticate Company
Route::post('/Register', [CompanyAuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [CompanyAuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/logout', [CompanyAuthController::class, 'logout']);
Route::put('/Company/update', [CompanyAuthController::class, 'update']);


// Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
//     // Route::put('/Company/update', [CompanyAuthController::class, 'update']);
// });

// Authenticate Employee
Route::post('/Employee/AddEmployee', [EmployeeAuthContoller::class, 'addEmployeee']);
Route::get('/Employee/getAll', [EmployeeAuthContoller::class, 'index']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Here is my auth.php : 'I use company guard for this issue ':

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'company' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum', // Use Sanctum driver
            'provider' => 'companies', // Use the 'companies' provider
        ],

        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum', // Use Sanctum driver
            'provider' => 'employees', // Use the 'employees' provider
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'companies' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Company::class,
        ],

        'employees' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'table' => App\Models\Employee::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    | The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
    | generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
    | quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure laravel server and databse server is running

Comment: everything is running because all the other apis i have work with no error only the put route don't work